# Spark dataset partitions with cassandra creating one big chunk of parquet file along with many small ones

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

As part of my spark cassandra connector test have facing issues in writing even sized parquet files from cassandra data.

Problem is spark dataset parquet write operation is creating one single big file (actual data) with many small files (just with header). Not sure how to solve this problem.

Command used

```
val df = spark.read.cassandraFormat("tab", "ks")
               .options(ReadConf.SplitSizeInMBParam.option(32))
               .load()
df.write.parquet("")
```

> 4 with_32_split/part-00318-ceb0dac6-6b32-4278-bcf6-8bee9fb46d72-c000.snappy.parquet
>
> 4 with_32_split/part-00319-ceb0dac6-6b32-4278-bcf6-8bee9fb46d72-c000.snappy.parquet
>
> 4 with_32_split/part-00320-ceb0dac6-6b32-4278-bcf6-8bee9fb46d72-c000.snappy.parquet
>
> 4 with_32_split/part-00321-ceb0dac6-6b32-4278-bcf6-8bee9fb46d72-c000.snappy.parquet
>
> 1717572   -->
>   with_32_split/part-00322-ceb0dac6-6b32-4278-bcf6-8bee9fb46d72-c000.snappy.parquet

Comment: you can repartition before saving?

Comment: Re-partition is one of the solutions but would like to avoid that expensive solution, instead i need a way to read even sized spark partitions directly from data source. 
Have tried excluding empty partitions with 
`
df.foreachPartition(partition => {
if (partition.nonEmpty) {
accum.add(1)
}
}
)
val df2 = df.coalesce(accum.value)"
`
But still getting skewed data with odd sizes.

Does any body came across this situation and is there a workaround for cassandra data source?